# bypass activation lock on i pod touch 5th generation

Tags: ipod-touch

how do I bypass a activation lock for a I pod touch 5th generation if I can't get a hold of previous users apple id and password

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to contact the previous owner to remove the activation lock.